# Участник с золотым знаком по метке числится в списке закрывших вопрос как дубликат, но следом указаны ещё другие участники

Tags: поддержка, предложение, причины-закрытия, дубликаты, золотые-знаки

Наблюдается [такая картина](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/962307/176217):

> [image: Дубликат]

Вопрос закрыт как дубликат участником с золотым знаком по метке, при этом в списке закрывших вопрос уже присутствует другой участник с золотым знаком по той же метке. Как такое возможно?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Суть в том, что участники, перечисленные в списке закрывашек, не обязательно голосовали за закрытие по той же причине, что указана как итоговая в закрытом вопросе. Об этом есть соответствующий feature request на MSE: ["Closed by" is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16674/339911).

Т.е. предыдущий участник с золотым молотом по метке на самом деле предложил закрыть вопрос по причине, отличной от "дубликат вопроса" (например, "неясна суть вопроса"), и в таком голосовании золото по метке не даёт ему какого бы то ни было преимущества. Итоговая фраза, конечно, вводит в заблуждение, и как упомянуто на MSE, хорошо было бы разнести списки участников, голосующих по разным причинам. По крайней мере выделить два списка:

1. Участники, голосовавшие так как сказано в причине закрытия;
2. Участники, голосовавшие иначе.

Кстати, для закрытых как "не по теме" подобное разделение [присутствует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/965241/176217):

> [image: кто так, кто сяк]